# How can I play a wav sound on the server side using cgi?

Tags: apache, cgi, server-side, wav

How can I run a command from a (bash) CGI script to play a wav sound **on the server side**?

Comment: I want the sound to play out of a speaker connected to the web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute your command line audio player as described by nak, but this may not work due to the permissions of the user running Apache.  By default Apache is run as www-data:www-data (or apache:apache or www:www on some distros).  As a quick fix/test you can set Apache to run as a user that has permissions to access the audio device on the machine by modifying your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (or /etc/httpd/httpd.conf") file to have:

```
 User USER_THAT_CAN_PLAY_AUDIO
 Group USER_THAT_CAN_PLAY_AUDIO
```

Warning: this is not secure and is not intended to be a permanent solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Content-type: text/plain
echo ""
echo "Server is playing sine.wav!"
aplay -q sine.wav
```

Comment: I am about to try this, but I tried with mplayer like this and it gave me an error along the lines of "could not open speakers".

Comment: Well, if this doesn't work then there may be another issue that needs to be resolved first.

Comment: turns out it won't play any audio, even locally.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this old question looking how to solve the same problem: to have my personal Apache webserver warning me when someone makes a specific request (in my case a call for chat without the need to have any IM running).

**The solution below is what I use on Slackware 14.1**: according to your distro *[YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary)*.

- launch `visudo`
- add the line `TheUserRunningApache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/play` (TheUserRunningApache is the user name used by your Apache)
- In the PHP page you want to play a sound add this line: `system ("sudo /usr/bin/play SOUND.WAV");`

If you don't want to give access to Apache to the `/usr/bin` folder, even if limited just to `play`, you can copy the `sox` executable (the program used to run `/usr/bin/play`) elsewhere, but you'll have to modify the last two instructions above accordingly.